# How to switch between repositories in Gradle when build locally or in CI

Tags: gradle, gitlab, environment-variables, build.gradle

I want to switch between repositories when I build projects locally or in CI. I read here https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/variables/predefined_variables.html that Gitlab creates environment variable 'CI' and want to use it. I do next:

```
if (System.getenv('CI') != null) {
    repositories {
        println 'CI=' + System.getenv('CI')
        mavenCentral()
        maven {
            url 'myrepo'
        }
    }
} else {
    repositories {
        println '*CI= ' + System.getenv('CI')
        mavenCentral()
        mavenLocal()
    }
}
```

But when I build in CI I see that CI=null. How properly define repository according to where I build project?

UPDATE: I'm using kaniko in gitlab-ci. It works fine in projects where is no kaniko.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CI variable must be defined in gitlab-ci with --build-arg and in project Dockerfile with ARG instruction:

Dockerfile:

```
ARG CI
```

gitlab-ci:

```
build:
  stage: build
  script:
    - /kaniko/executor
      --build-arg CI="${CI}"
```

With ARG instruction I tell the Dockerfile to let Docker know, that it expects a variable named CI to be passed to it during the build. And --build-arg sets the value.